# prototype mismatch with decltype and auto

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, auto, decltype

Consider the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
    int _id;
public:
    decltype(_id) getId();
};

decltype(MyClass::_id) MyClass::getId()
{
    return _id;
}
```

It compiles fine.

However when I make a template class out of it:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    int _id;
public:
    decltype(_id) getId();
};

template <class T>
decltype(MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()
{
    return _id;
}
```

I get:

```
test.cpp:10:27: error: prototype for 'decltype (MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()' does not match any in class 'MyClass<T>'
 decltype(MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()                                                                                
                           ^
test.cpp:6:19: error: candidate is: decltype (((MyClass<T>*)(void)0)->MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()
     decltype(_id) getId();
                   ^
```

Why is that?
Why the different types

- `decltype (MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()`
- `decltype (((MyClass<T>*)(void)0)->MyClass<T>::_id)`

I could fix it by defining the body in the class:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    int _id;
public:
    decltype(_id) getId() { return _id; }
};
```

Trailing return type suffers a similar problem:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    int _id;
public:
    auto getId() -> decltype(_id);
};

template <class T>
auto MyClass<T>::getId() -> decltype(MyClass<T>::_id)
{
    return _id;
}
```

error:

```
test.cpp:10:6: error: prototype for 'decltype (MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()' does not match any in class 'MyClass<T>'
 auto MyClass<T>::getId() -> decltype(MyClass<T>::_id)
      ^
test.cpp:6:10: error: candidate is: decltype (((MyClass<T>*)this)->MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()
     auto getId() -> decltype(_id);
          ^
```

- `decltype (MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()`
- `decltype (((MyClass<T>*)this)->MyClass<T>::_id) MyClass<T>::getId()`

g++ 5.3.0

Comment: Simply using `decltype( MyClass<T>::_id )` instead of `decltype( _id )` in the declaration fixed it for me. (Also gcc 5.3.0). I'm not sure how to interpret this evidence. Basically, just make sure the declaration and definition are as similar as possible -- i.e. use `decltype( MyClass<T>::_id )` in both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the draft standard [N4582](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf) *§5.1.1/p13 General [expr.prim.general]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static
>   member function of a class can only be used:
>
> (13.1) —  as part of a class member access (5.2.5) in which the object
>   expression refers to the member’s class<sup>63</sup> or a class
>   derived from that class, or
>
> (13.2) — to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), or
>
> **(13.3) — if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it
>   appears in an unevaluated operand. [Example:**
>
> ```
> struct S {
> int m;
> };
> int i = sizeof(S::m); // OK
> int j = sizeof(S::m + 42); // OK
> ```
>
> **— end example ]**
>
> <sub>63) This also applies when the object expression is an implicit
>   (*this) (9.3.1).</sub>

Also from *§7.1.6.2/p4 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]*(**Emphasis Mine**):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as
>   follows:
>
> (4.1) — if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized
>   class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity
>   named by e. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of
>   overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> (4.2) — otherwise, if e is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where
>   `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> (4.3) — otherwise, if e is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T`
>   is the type of `e`;
>
> (4.4) — otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.
>
> **The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5).**
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> const int&& foo();
> int i;
> struct A { double x; };
> const A* a = new A();
> decltype(foo()) x1 = 17; // type is const int&&
> decltype(i) x2; // type is int
> decltype(a->x) x3; // type is double
> decltype((a->x)) x4 = x3; // type is const double&
> ```
>
> — end example ] [ Note: The rules for determining types involving
>   decltype(auto) are specified in 7.1.6.4. — end note ]

Consequently, since `decltype` is an unevaluated operand the code is legitimate and should compile.

One clean workaround would be to use `decltype(auto)`:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
  int _id;  
public:
  decltype(auto) getId();
};

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) MyClass<T>::getId() {
  return _id;
}
```

Above code is accepted by GCC/CLANG/VC++.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is `g++` bug.

I've tried your code in Visual Studio 2015:

> Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped

Edit: I found [workaround](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c6afa8c7c5eb6ac3):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    T _id = {0};
public:
    decltype(((MyClass<T>*)nullptr)->_id) getId();
};

template <class T>
decltype(((MyClass<T>*)nullptr)->_id) MyClass<T>::getId()
{
    return _id;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> f;
    auto n = f.getId();

    std::cout << n << '\n'; // output: 0
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: Code that fails in GCC _and_ Clang and works in VC++ is probably wrong, TBH.

Comment: If it even compiles with VC++ doesn't mean that it's a bug in g++.

Comment: @ildjarn the code compiles with Clang, [demo](http://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:'template+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+MyClass%0A%7B%0A++++int+_id%3B%0Apublic:%0A++++auto+getId()+-%3E+decltype(_id)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aauto+MyClass%3CT%3E::getId()+-%3E+decltype(MyClass%3CT%3E::_id)%0A%7B%0A++++return+_id%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(binary:!t),version:3).

Comment: @sergej : Not when you make `int` the return type of the in-class `getId` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be GCC [Bug 57712](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57712).

Example code from the bug description:

```
struct Test {
  int method(int value) { return value; }

  template <typename T>
  auto test(T value) -> decltype(this->method(value));
};

template <typename T>
auto Test::test(T value) -> decltype(this->method(value)) {
  return this->method(value);
}
```